# What, aside from binocular vision, eye count, and goggle style, is the difference between 1 eyed and 2 eyed minions?

Tags: character-identification, despicable-me, minions

First seen in *Despicable Me*, what, aside from binocular vision, eye count, and goggle style, are the differences between 1 eyed and 2 eyed minions? [image: Minions] *Image courtesy of http://ihdwallpapers.com/*

Comment: Why would you expect there to be other differences?

Answer (score 19):

**There is no official information on it, but I do have a theory: identification**

As per the [Despicable Me Wikia page on Minions](https://despicableme.fand.com/wiki/Minions) (emphasis mine):

> Minions are a similar size and shape, **but have unique features to tell
>   them apart**, such as height, **number of eyes**, roundness or secondary
>   features such as hair, eye/pupil size or clothing.

From this, it seems that there **is no difference between single-eye and two-eye minions**.  The number of eyes is simply one of the varying features of the minions used to differentiate them, you know, so you can tell if it's Steve:

[image: Steve]

or Dave

[image: Dave]

who, to me at least, seem identical in all other respects!

Comment: Why the downvote?  I cite sources to back up my argument.  If somebody can find evidence that disproves what I have said, please present it.  Otherwise your downvote is unfounded!

Comment: The down vote isn't mine, but are you _seriously_ using a wikia site as a source?

Comment: @SQB Considering it is a wikia *devoted* to the franchise, and other wikia's are classified as completely reputable sources, amongst other Memory Alpha and Wookieepedia, yes I *am* seriously using a wikia as a credible source

Comment: @TheDoc, in all fairness,  see [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7384/what-exactly-is-the-standing-of-information-from-memory-alpha).   You really shouldn't rely on wikia for unverifiable facts.   That notwithstanding,   your claim (it seems that there is not difference...) doesn't follow from the quote anyhow.

Comment: @ThePopMachine At the time I made the above comment, MA was considered to be a great source and the Meta post you've linked to didn't exist.  Nevertheless, I don't see how you can say my argument doesn't follow from the quote.  As part of the means of distinguishing individual minions, the number of eyes is a trait used to differentiate them.  Even if the quote is unsupported, it's quite a reasonable argument when you consider it; how else do you think characters can determine which minion they are talking to?

Comment: @TheDoc, I don't think the quote was intended to mean the differences in appearance can't inform other differences.   I get that the letter of the words can be read that way,  but it doesn't matter because I don't think that was the intent behind the phrasing.   That with the fact it's "just a wikia" means I don't buy it as evidence.   A better answer would just be:  there's no evidence anywhere of any such difference, rather than trying to shoehorn evidence to your point.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I've changed my answer a little bit, so hopefully that will make it a bit clearer 

Comment: (Btw, @Praxis trends to sometimes do this too, so you're in good company)

Comment: Unaccepted theory response. Enough time has passed and sequels made for there to be a more definitive answer.